# React navigation 2 - shared view across app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing a music player app, and the player view should be accessible from and shared across all other views. I'm using react navigation 2.
this is the structure of my app:

```
 
a) Root stack nav
  b) Player Stack nav
    1) Player View
  c) Home tab nav
    1) Tab 1 stack nav
    2) Tab 2 stack nav
    3) Tab 3 stack nav
```

all of the leaf nodes in home tab nav (all of the views), need to access player view. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this using `react-navigation`
In my example I have basically 2 stack :

1. `Login stack`
2. `Auth stack`

You can configure yours as per requirement.

[click here](https://reactnavigation.org/)  for more information

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
.....

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: Home });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Login: LoginForm, Signup: SignupForm, ForgetPassword: ForgetPassword });


export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: LoginForm,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

Comment: actually, I've tried this, but switch navigator does not behave as expected in my case. switch navigator can not navigate 'back'. if you pop the navigation stack in switch navigator, the app closes. I need to be able to maintain my navigation history and be able to go back from player view, to whatever view that initiated it.